Firewall drops DHCP with full allowed or disabled Firewall in Fresh unchanged Windows 11 23H2 Installation
I installed a fresh Win 11 23H2 (with lot problems caused to broken Installer-PE, but not the point)
The Network Connection dont work. Its a Reaktek 2,5GbE 8125 Adapter.
I tried:
diffent settings like manual IP, set manual link negotiation,
disable Firewall, allow all in/outbound traffic, reinstall driver, deactivate different protocols in Network Adapter Settings, Added GPOs FW Allow rules and restarted router.
I also checked:
dhcpd router logs, checked windows log files, Win FW Logs and
Time Settings.

Comments:
Interesting is, that if I set link negotiation (eg. to 100Mbps) to manual value, it flips every second between the Max 2,5Gbps to the set value.
Also, with full out/in allowed, activated firewall the pflogs drops a lot, inclusive DHCP from 0.0.0.0:68 to 255.255.255.255:67.
It seems any FW Problem to be.

How can I make my network connection work?

Your question related to Powershell should be asked another question, as it is not the main problem of your question.

So wouldnt it be most logical to conclude this behaviour might stem from the broken install proces ? Remake your installation media and run through the install process again without errors. Second is checking physical things. Different ports in the router, different cable, ... Thirdly trying from a different operating system, usually through using a linux live environment on USB.

Simplest answer: reinstall Windows after remaking the InstallUSB from the Media Creation Tool - the WinPE sources/boot.wim being broken is a sign the ISO was corrupted, the WinPE WIM was tampered with, or it was manually modifed incorrectly. The only other thing that could cause an install issue is using a custom answer file that wasn't correctly configured or tested for errors prior to exiting Windows SIM

(Cont'd...) Upon OOBE exiting and when at the Desktop, prior to doing anything else install the CPU chipset drivers (CPU related drivers (chipset, thermal, etc.) are the only hardware drivers Windows Update cannot install), reboot when done, then try connecting ethernet, install all Windows Updates (enabling Windows Update to install third party drivers), and finally install software. If DHCP cannot occur, check the router system log as it's highly unlikely it's Windows since Windows always allows DHCP by default, as do the default network driver settings for any arbitrary interface.

It was a driver problem, that that the DHCP not work correctly. I used a external Wifi Stick, which recognized by Windows per default and then used Windows Update. Different Versions from Reaktek for the Card didn't work well. Only the official Windows Update Version works. Alwaxs the same problems with Windows. World, pls use Linux :p
